# Modify Global Mac OS X Path

Tags: macos

What is the best way to permanently change the Mac OS X path variable?  I've tried to add a .profile file in my user home directory with the below path, but that didn't work. Right now I have to run the export command every time I open up a new instance of the console.  Any ideas?

export PATH=/Users/tom/sshfs-binaries:$PATH

Answer (score 4):

If that's for a single user, you can add `export PATH=/new/path:${PATH}` to `~/.bash_profile`. If it's going to be really global (for all users), then add it to `/etc/profile` and make sure the users have permission to access the path you're including. After that, you need to re-launch the shell, or reload the configurations with `source /etc/profile` or `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: how would I make it applicable for just one user?

Comment: @C12: put that export command on the `/home/<user>/.bash_profile` file.

Comment: I'm not the admin of this machine and I don't have a user directory in the /home/ dir. I also don't have a .bash_profile file under /Users/username. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect this happened before the question was migrated, but `/home/<user>/.bash_profile` is incorrect. On OS X it's `/Users/<username>/.bash_profile` So for example: `/Users/c12/.bash_profile`, just create the file if it doesn't exist and changes will be automatically picked up at next login / terminal invocation.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Jason is correct. When I wrote that comment I forgot the question was about OS X.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [~/.MacOSX/environment.plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002093-BCIJIJBH) (also [this](http://wiki.lyx.org/Mac/Environment) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1067/_index.html)).

"**Note**: Any changes to [~/.MacOSX/environment.plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002093-BCIJIJBH) require that you logout and login again for the change to take effect."